# model object is null

Tags: android, oop, android-togglebutton

i'm trying to save list items by toggle button click.
when i click on toggle button my app crashes, i debugged my app and found that the model object every time is null !!
can anyone tell me why it is null ? how can i solve this?
i tried to handle toggle button click out of the adapter class but in vain

here is myAdapter.java

```
package com.example.remon.my_app2;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.TextureView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

import com.example.remon.my_app2.models.CatModel;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Remon on 9/27/2017.
 */

public class myAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    ArrayList<CatModel> catModels;
    Context mContext;


    ToggleButton btnTglFavourite;
    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
    CatModel catModel;
    public myAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<CatModel>catModels){
        this.mContext=context;
        this.catModels=catModels;

    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return catModels == null ? 0 : catModels.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return catModels.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int id) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View ConvertedView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View view=ConvertedView;
        if (view==null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)
                    mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_1_items,viewGroup,false);

            CatModel catModel = (CatModel)getItem(position);
            TextView txtCatName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtCat);
             txtCatName.setText(catModel.getCatName());
        }
        btnTglFavourite = (ToggleButton)view.findViewById(R.id.favoriteToggleButton);
//            btnTglFavourite.setChecked(false);
//            if (databaseHelper.check(catModelss.getCatName())){
//                btnTglFavourite.setChecked(true);
//            }
        btnTglFavourite.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (!databaseHelper.check(catModel.getCatName())){  //////object is null !!
                    databaseHelper.insert(catModel.getCatName());
                    Toast.makeText(mContext,"in database: " +catModel.getCatName(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {databaseHelper.deleteRow(catModel.getCatName());}
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The catmodel you are using below

```
    if (!databaseHelper.check(catModel.getCatName())){
                databaseHelper.insert(catModel.getCatName());
                Toast.makeText(mContext,"in database: "+catModel.getCatName(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else {databaseHelper.deleteRow(catModel.getCatName());}
```

is the global/field reference which never got initialized.

Solution should be

```
    public View getView(int position, View ConvertedView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        final CatModel catModel = (CatModel)getItem(position);
        View view=ConvertedView;
        if (view==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)
                    mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_1_items,viewGroup,false);

            TextView txtCatName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtCat);
             txtCatName.setText(catModel.getCatName());
        }
        btnTglFavourite = (ToggleButton)view.findViewById(R.id.favoriteToggleButton);
//            btnTglFavourite.setChecked(false);
//            if (databaseHelper.check(catModelss.getCatName())){
//                btnTglFavourite.setChecked(true);
//            }
        btnTglFavourite.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (!databaseHelper.check(catModel.getCatName())){  //////object is null !!
                    databaseHelper.insert(catModel.getCatName());
                    Toast.makeText(mContext,"in database: " +catModel.getCatName(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {databaseHelper.deleteRow(catModel.getCatName());}
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
```

Comment: if (!databaseHelper.check(catModel.getCatName())){  //////object is null !!..at this line i have an error says that variable 'catModel' might have not been initialized, how can i initialize this variable it is final !! can u help me with this ??

Comment: the catModel is not null anymore ! :) thanks for ur help..but my app still crashes at this line
if (!databaseHelper.check(catModel.getCatName())){
could u plz tell me why this happens ?? or how i can find the reason for this ?

Answer (score 0):

### Try this

```
package com.example.remon.my_app2;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.TextureView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

import com.example.remon.my_app2.models.CatModel;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Remon on 9/27/2017.
 */

public class myAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    ArrayList<CatModel> catModels;
    Context mContext;


    ToggleButton btnTglFavourite;
    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
    CatModel catModel;
    public myAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<CatModel>catModels){
        this.mContext=context;
        this.catModels=catModels;

    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return catModels == null ? 0 : catModels.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return catModels.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int id) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View ConvertedView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View view=ConvertedView;
        if (view==null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)
                    mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_1_items,viewGroup,false);


            TextView txtCatName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtCat);
             txtCatName.setText(catModels.get(position).getCatName());
        }
        btnTglFavourite = (ToggleButton)view.findViewById(R.id.favoriteToggleButton);
//            btnTglFavourite.setChecked(false);
//            if (databaseHelper.check(catModelss.getCatName())){
//                btnTglFavourite.setChecked(true);
//            }
        btnTglFavourite.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (!databaseHelper.check(catModels.get(position).getCatName())){  //////object is null !!
                    databaseHelper.insert(catModels.get(position).getCatName());
                    Toast.makeText(mContext,"in database: " +catModels.get(position).getCatName(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {databaseHelper.deleteRow(catModels.get(position).getCatName());}
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: ur solution works :) but my app still crashes here 
if (!databaseHelper.check(catModels.get(position).getCatName())){ 
 i don't know why..could u help me with this ?

Comment: First check catModels.get(position).getCatName()!=null and databaseHelper also

Comment: catModels.get(position).getCatName()!=null but databaseHelper is null..when i debugged the databaseHelper class i found it crashed at this line         Cursor res = db.rawQuery(sql,null);                  i don't know why this happens..can u help me ?

Comment: because you are not create the object of databaseHelper you can create object in constructor.

Comment: i've created object of the databaseHelper but my error is still the same at the same line

Comment: i found my fault..my sqlQuery was wrong..thanks a lot for ur help :)